# Why didn't see ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S5 in Ubuntu?

Tags: acpi

I used Virtualbox to install two VMs, 1 CentOS 8, 1 Ubuntu 18.04.

After OS boot, I press "ACPI shutdown" in both VMs but got the different result:

CentOS 8:

```
[   42.562604] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S5
[   42.564738] reboot: Power down
```

Ubuntu 18.04:

```
         Starting Power-Off...
[   75.167832] reboot: Power down
```

We can see there is no ACPI-related string when Ubuntu shutting down, but both using the same version of Virtualbox, I think the BIOS is the same.

I can see this log in both VMs:

```
[    0.896151] ACPI: (supports S0 S5)
```

Can I say Ubuntu is not using ACPI ? I checked the grub of Ubuntu, it didn't assign acpi=off

What setting/config caused Ubuntu not to use ACPI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably Ubuntu and CentOS are using different console log levels, so Ubuntu filters out the `ACPI: Preparing...` message and probably outputs a different message from the shutdown scripts instead.

Ubuntu's `Starting Power-Off...` message is not prefixed by `[ <uptime in seconds> ]` like all kernel log messages are, so it's probably produced by a different mechanism.

The log messages produced by the kernel are assigned to priority classes, and the low-priority messages are normally not displayed on the console. Please run `sudo sysctl kernel.printk` on both systems and see if the different distributions use different values. The command should output four numbers: the first one specifies the highest kernel message priority class to filter out.

[Documentation on the `kernel.printk` values can be found here.](https://mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/admin-guide/sysctl/kernel.rst#925)

Comment: CentOS 8 log level is 7 4 1 7, Ubuntu log level is 4 4 1 7, changed it to 7 4 1 7 then can see the ACPI S5 messages.